# TypeError: $object is not a function jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax

```
    var opts             = $.extend({}, $.ias.defaults, options); 
     function get_scroll_treshold(pure)
    {
        el = $(opts.container).find(opts.item).last();

        if (el.size() == 0) return 0;

        treshold = el.offset().top + el.height();

        if (!pure)
            treshold += opts.tresholdMargin;

        return treshold;
    }
```

Hello, this is the code snippet above ^. the issue I am having is it throws this error:

```
TypeError: $(opts.container).find(opts.item).last is not a function
```

I am using https://github.com/webcreate/infinite-ajax-scroll this plugin. I went through the issues listed on the github page and none seems to mention the issue I am having. 
any ideas suggestions please ?

Comment: Does jQuery work anywhere else on the page? Are you using any other plugins which might change the value of the `$` object?

Comment: no the value isnt changed. and yes jquery works all around the page

Comment: I don't see `el` being initialized; like `var el` or something !

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems correct, but you can try to do so:

```
var elements = $('selector');

var lastElement = elements.filter(':last');
// or 
lastElement = elements.eq(elements.length - 1);
```

Comment: I dont get you?can you use the names I have on my code? like opts.container etc? sorry its just confusing what you are trying to do

Comment: `var elements = $(opts.container).find(opts.item);` and `el == lastElement`